# Android: LiveWallpaper how to set in landscape from asets

Tags: android, image, live-wallpaper, android-assets

Hiii,

I had make application to set `LiveWallpaper`. It works fine, but when i see in landscape mode `Image` set on left portion and right portion is black. How i set in full screen. Image come from assets, so i don't use different images like drawable folder for `Landscape` and `Portrait`.

Please help me. . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am change `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapImage, 0, 0, null);` to `canvas.drawBitmapMesh(bitmapImage, 1, 1, vertices, 0, null, 0, null);` and my problem was solved.